# Make unique pairs of dicts from a list of dicts based on conditions

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, combinations

I have a list of dicts, I sorted it like this:

```
the_list = [
{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'football'},
{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'football'},
{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'football'},
{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},
{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},
{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},  
{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},
{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},
{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},
]
```

The list have n length, so there will be more dicts with different name key and sport_type key. I need to create a list of unique dict pairs based on same sport_type and != different name. Like this:

```
need_to = [
[{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'football'},{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'football'}],
[{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'football'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'football'}],
[{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'football'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'football'}],
[{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'hokey'}],
[{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'hokey'}],
[{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'hokey''}], 
[{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'tennis'}],
[{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'tennis'}],
[{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'tennis'}],
]
```

So there is no reverse duplicates a+b, b+a. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for this.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [c for c in itertools.combinations(the_list, 2) if c[0]['sport_type'] == c[1]['sport_type']]
[({'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'football'},{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'football'}),
 ({'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'football'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'football'}),
 ({'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'football'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'football'}),
 ({'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'hokey'}),
 ({'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'hokey'}),
 ({'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'hokey'}),
 ({'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'tennis'}),
 ({'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'tennis'}),
 ({'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'tennis'})]
```

Answer (score 1):

First group by the `sport_type` (using a dictionary), then use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combination):

```
from itertools import combinations

the_list = [
{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'football'},
{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'football'},
{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'football'},
{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},
{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},
{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'hokey'},
{'name': 'bobby', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},
{'name': 'jenny', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},
{'name': 'karl', 'sport_type': 'tennis'},
]

groups = {}
for d in the_list:
    groups.setdefault(d['sport_type'], []).append(d)

result = [list(pair) for group in groups.values() for pair in  combinations(group, 2)]

for pair in result:
    print(pair)
```